# An Access problem: Not getting required output while building a report

Tags: sql, select, ms-access-2007

I have created a report in Access and I have written a query for fetching records from 
multiple tables as follows:

```
SELECT BuildingDetails.*, Contractors.Item, ActionDetails.ActionType
FROM Contractors 
INNER JOIN (BuildingDetails 
    INNER JOIN (ActionDetails 
        INNER JOIN DormData ON ActionDetails.ActionID = DormData.ActionID) 
    ON BuildingDetails.BuildingID = DormData.BuildingID) 
ON Contractors.ID = DormData.ItemID;
```

Now what I want is only `actiontype=repair` or `actionid=1` get retrieved by the query. We have two `actontype` "repair" and "replace".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you only need to filter using `actiontype = 'repair'` (I further guess that `ActionID` is an autonumber and you have a row `{ActionID = 1, actiontype = 'repair'}` only by chance... but this is maybe extrapolating too far :)

I'm surprised @David Steele's answer works in Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) because he's removed the parentheses from the `JOIN` clauses (however if it does -- suggesting a linked table -- then you should "accept" that answer). But I too could resist 'neatening them up' so that the `ON` clauses are close to the table names:

```
SELECT BuildingDetails.*, Contractors.Item, ActionDetails.ActionType
  FROM ((DormData 
         INNER JOIN Contractors 
            ON Contractors.ID = DormData.ItemID)
         INNER JOIN BuildingDetails 
            ON BuildingDetails.BuildingID = DormData.BuildingID)
         INNER JOIN ActionDetails
            ON ActionDetails.ActionID = DormData.ActionID
 WHERE ActionDetails.ActionType = 'repair';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have reformatted you query a little to neaten it up.  You haven't specified what the data looks like for the filter but based on what you have said I would go with something like the following

```
SELECT BuildingDetails.*, 
Contractors.Item, 
ActionDetails.ActionType 
FROM Contractors 
INNER JOIN DormData ON Contractors.ID = DormData.ItemID
INNER JOIN ActionDetails ON DormData.ActionID = ActionDetails.ActionID
INNER JOIN BuildingDetails ON DormData.BuildingID = BuildingDetails.BuildingID
WHERE ActionDetails.ActionType = 'Repair' OR ActionID=1
```

If ActionID is a lookup column that relates ActionID(1) to ActionType ('Repair')  then you don't need the or and can stick to one or other of the conditions in the WHERE Clause.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hello david i have another problem in access project.

Comment: i have created a form in which there are multiple combo box field.based on these select i have to search my database and show it a excel sheet. i totally confused ,how i can i do it? plz help

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your select statement to fix the issue:

```
where actiondetails.actiontype = 'repair' or actiondetails.actionid = 1
```

Comment: grant can u give me your email id